# Drawn image not moving on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I make the game with html canvas.I need to move the image sprite but my code only redraw the image on the same position.Where is problem?The code is here

```
class Duck{
   constructor(x,y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.skin = 'img/path/';
   }

   draw() {    
     var img = new Image();  
     img.src = this.skin;
     img.onload = function () {    
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.drawImage(img,this.x, this.y);
     ctx.restore();
     }
    
   }

   move(){
         this.x+=10;
         this.y+=10;     
   }
}


var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var d = new Duck(0,0);

//this function called from another file and it works
function mainLoop() {
    d.move();
    d.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code fixed:

- You don't need `ctx.restore();`
- You need to store `this` context in the `draw` method, for reference in the `img.onload` callback

```js
class Duck {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.skin = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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';
    }

    draw() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = this.skin;
        const that = this;
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, that.x, that.y);
        }

    }

    move() {
        this.x += 10;
        this.y += 10;
    }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var d = new Duck(0, 0);

//this function called from another file and it works
function mainLoop() {
    d.move();
    d.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

mainLoop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" height="600px" width="600px"></canvas>
```